# ( RDS ) MySQL to MySQL migration within aws

Tags: mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

**RDS MySQL to MySQL migration**

I've 2 MySQL(5.7) RDS instance in my AWS account namely prod & dev.
My task here to migrate all objects from Prod instance to Dev in order to make sure all prod objects exist in dev.

Both MySQL instance sits in same aws account.

What would be right approach so that I can further re-research about it.

Answer (score 1):

If your instances are accessible over the net than you can simply dump the `prod` instance on the `dev` instance via the host having required utilities and access to both instances:

```
mysqldump --host 10.20.30.40 \
          -u myaccount1 \
          -pmypassword1 \
          --all-databases \
          --events \
          --routines  \
| mysql --host 20.30.40.50 \
        -u myaccount2 \
        -pmypassword2
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. i have tried to test with one db but it always returns no database selected.

Comment: mysqldump 
--no-data ^
--triggers ^
--routines ^
--single-transaction ^
--column-statistics=0 ^
--host host ^
db ^
-ppassword ^
-u root | mysql --host host -ppassword -f -u username